# excel vba specific row copy paste by cell referance

Tags: excel, vba

I have to select specific row from so many rows and copy paste to another sheet but I don't want to specified value of cell if it takes value from particular cell
my code is

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim rngG As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Sheets("Urban-Ward_vise").Select
    Set rngG = Range("G1", Range("G65536").End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In rngG
        If cell.Value = "BAVLA" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            ActiveCell.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next cell
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select

End Sub
```

I want to select rows from Urban-Ward_vise and paste in sheet1

in

```
If cell.Value = "BAVLA" Then
```

I don't want put value "BAVLA" but I want to read the value from sheet1 cell like c5 so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

It would be worth you reading [how to avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim rngG As Range
Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Urban-Ward_vise")
    Set rngG = .Range("G1", .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rngG
    If cell.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value Then 'specify sheet name and cell here
        cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for help and if there is Urban-Ward_vise and Sheet1 if there is no match so 
how to add do nothing in code

Comment: Not sure I follow. Currently the code only does something if the column G value matches C5.